# IDesignTimeDbContextFactory not always needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Previously i had to implement IDesignTimeDbContextFactory to get migrations running, e.g:
PM > Add-Migration Initial
PM > Update-Database

If not, the console threw an error and led me here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#use-idesigntimedbcontextfactory.

So i did what it suggested and got migrations running.
After that i have created new projects, and i didn't have to implement the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory. Migrations worked anyway. How is this possible?
Same .NET Core version (2.0) on all of the projects.

Do we always need to create a IDesignTimeDbContextFactory, or is it just in certain situations?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this apply? https://www.bountysource.com/issues/46781053-ef-core-2-0-design-time-dbcontext-discovery-changes

Comment: Might be thanks, i found the discussion on github so i'll post the question there as well and get back when i've gotten a response.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, here it goes:
If you have a default constructor in your DbContext or are using the Program.BuildWebHost() pattern established in the ASP.NET Core 2.0 project templates, you typically won't need an IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation.

In 2.0.0-preview1 Program.BuildWebHost() wasn't used and you needed a design-time factory.

See this thread for full discussion:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9033

Answer (score 1):

As Dan Banan stated, if a `DbContext` has a default constructor, it won't need an `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` at design time. However, if it needs to be configured from `Startup`, it will need a constructor which takes accepts `DbContextOptions<T>` and invokes the corresponding `base` constructor. However, this will create another issue. The `DbContext`'s `OnConfigure` method will be called regardless of which constructor is used.

To account for these details, I've found the following pattern to be useful:

**DbContext Configuration and Dependency Injection**

```
serviceCollection
    .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDb"),
        ServiceLifetime.Transient
    );
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SureshotDbContext()
    {
        // This allows for instantiation at design time.
    }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) :
        base(options)
    {
        // This allows for configuration in real applications.
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(
        DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder
    )
    {
        if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            return;
        }

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(nameof(TDbContext));
    }
}
```